# Adicionar DIV's com ID's diferentes usando Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Tentei varias gambiarras (infelizmente) porém não consigo achar uma solução para minha idéia.
Eu tenho um "app" que cria uma lista de tarefas, só que eu gostaria de adicionar a minha lista um id diferente para cada `div` adicionado dentro do `div` principal.

```
var main = function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var tarefa = $('input[name=tarefa]').val();
    var conferir = $('.item').text();
         if(tarefa==conferir){
       alert("Tarefa já foi adicionada!");
     }

//Adiciona um div com o id item dentro do div com classe lista-tarefa
  $('.lista-tarefa').append('<div id="item">' + tarefa + '</div>');
    $('input[name=tarefa]').val('');
  })
  $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    if (confirm("Deseja apagar?")){
    $(this).remove();
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(main)
```

Na parte do comentário ele sempre vai adicionar uma `div` com o id igual, porém eu gostaria de adicionar com id diferente para poder fazer uma validação de repetição quando o usuário inserir a tarefa.
Na pratica eu gostaria de adicionar um div com `id="item1"`, `id="item2"`, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a data da criação da div para garantir um id único para a div. Para gerar o id com base na data faça o seguinte:

```
var id = new Date().getTime();
```

Com isso você irá garantir unicidade nos ids gerados evitando conflitos.

Depois de gerar o `id` basta concatená-lo na sua `div` antes de adicionar na página.

Answer (score 1):

```
function guid() {
        return 'f' + (Math.random() * (1 << 30)).toString(16).replace('.', '');
}
```

Em um projeto que eu estou trabalhando, eu preciso gerar vários componentes e eu estou utilizando essa função para gerenciar os ids. Eu encontrei essa função em uma [bibilioteca](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8386225/) do facebook.

O que essa função faz é gerar um número aleatório que você pode atribuir em sua div.

**Exemplo**:

```
var main = function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var tarefa = $('input[name=tarefa]').val();
        var conferir = $('.item').text();
        if(tarefa==conferir){
            alert("Tarefa já foi adicionada!");
        }

        //Adiciona um div com o id item dentro do div com classe lista-tarefa
        $('.lista-tarefa').append('<div id="'+ guid() +'">' + tarefa + '</div>');
        $('input[name=tarefa]').val('');
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
        if (confirm("Deseja apagar?")){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve definir um contador e gerar o `id` dinamicamente:

```
var contador = 0; // <<<=========== CONTADOR DECLARADO AQUI

var main = function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var tarefa = $('input[name=tarefa]').val();
        var conferir = $('.item').text();
        if(tarefa==conferir){
            alert("Tarefa já foi adicionada!");
        }

        // gera o id e incrementa o contador para não gerar id's iguais.
        var id = "item" + contador; // <<<==== ID DECLARADO AQUI
        contador++;

        // repare que utilizamos o id definido anteriormente:
        $('.lista-tarefa').append('<div id="' + id + '">' + tarefa + '</div>');
        $('input[name=tarefa]').val('');

        $("#" + id).on("click", function () {
            if ( confirm("Deseja apagar?") ) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
        if (confirm("Deseja apagar?")){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Acredito que você tenha a intenção de também adicionar a classe `item` à tarefa criada. Use:

```
  $('.lista-tarefa').append('<div id="' + id + '" class="item">' + tarefa + '</div>');
    $('input[name=tarefa]').val('');
  });
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vinicius, tentei usar do seu modo porém faltou declarar a variavel contador, pois quando executo o código ele fala que a variavel não existe.
E caso eu inicie ela com 1 ou 0 ela sempre adiciona o mesmo numero.

Comment: não preciso adicionar uma classe ao final, eu estava usando classes para manipulação mesmo.

Na parte onde voce coloca o $("#" + id).on...
Não funciona uncaugth ReferenceError: id is not defined.

Comment: No meu código a variável `contador` esta declarada e inicializada, bem como `id` no seu escopo de uso. Vou destacar as declarações dessas variáveis no meu código, pois provavelmente faltou copiar alguma coisa para o seu código.

Comment: Removi o trecho final da resposta. Ficou confuso hehehe.